# Android: How to programmatically read/write Settings | Locations | My Places?

Tags: android, location, settings, storage

On my Galaxy S4, under Settings | Locations | My Places, there is a screen that lets you select and save your Home, work, and other custom locations (NOT to be confused with browser bookmarks. Google Bookmarks, or old Google Maps “My Places”).  Can I programmatically read these saved locations, and add new ones?  Is this a standard feature, or something Samsung customized?

Comment: It's Samsung. I just looked through the SDK and couldn't find any reference to it.

Comment: Thank you.  Can you briefly explain how I can look through the SDK?  My dev machine is a PC/Windows 7.  I’m using AndroidStudio.

Comment: Their SDK documentation is a PDF file. I just searched it for "places."